# Public file just for current session

Tags: php, joomla, permissions

I have a folder with multiple PDF files
The name of each is the session number that was created
What I want is that a user (unauthenticated) can download the PDF file corresponding to their session, but without access to other files (because the folder where the files are is public).
How can I fix this?
Note: All users are not authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you say "corresponding to your session", do you mean "to their session"?

The first thing to do is to prevent directory listing, the directory where your PDFs are sitting obviously. This can be easily done with an **.htaccess** file containing this single line:

> deny from all

Next, and with the assumption you were talking about *their* session, you can write a simple HTML link to download the PDF, such as

```
Download your PDF <a href="/public/path/to/download.php">here</a>.
```

where **download.php** is just a server-side *proxy* service script, such as

```
<?php
define('PDF_REPOSITORY', '/path/to/dir');

if (session_id() && file_exists(PDF_REPOSITORY . '/' . session_id() . ".pdf")) {
    readfile(PDF_REPOSITORY . '/' . session_id() . ".pdf");
}

?>
```

Here we exploit the fact that the server has the right to read a resource despite a client cannot, because of the *deny from all* restriction set above.

Obviously this proxy service is a very cutdown example that could be secured a lot more than that.

Comment: that's it! thanks for your help. And yes, it is "their session"